# How to mount the `D:\` disk of Windows in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, disk

I am unable to mount the `D:\` disk of windows in linux mint. What to do?

Comment: What happens when you try? What *did* you try?

Answer (score 3):

## Steps

**1. Discover your disk partitions :**

As root or super user display your partitions with file system types :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

result :

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    71682047    35737600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        71682048   134596607    31457280    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       134596608   625141759   245272576    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       134598656   201707519    33554432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       201709568   233166847    15728640    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       233168896   327540735    47185920   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       327542784   344319999     8388608   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9       344322048   396750847    26214400   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      396752896   449181695    26214400   83  Linux
/dev/sda11      449183744   543555583    47185920   83  Linux
```

This will show you some information about partitions witch can help you decide witch one is your D:/ (Size in blocks, filesystem type (vFat, NTFS ..etc) and index )

In this example, `/dev/sda1` is reserved to windows boot. `/dev/sda2` is C:\ and `/dev/sda3` is D:\

**2. Make sure you have NTFS-3G utility :**

`ntfs-3g` utility helps you mount windows filesystems in linux. Just type `ntfs-3g`. If it doesn't exist install it `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

**3. Create a mount point and mount your FS :**

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/wind_D
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /mnt/win_D
```